# Solution for OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of format - when matching ORB features with FlannBasedMatcher

Tags: c++, opencv3.0, orb

I tried to find good matches using ORB.My code is as follows:

```
Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector = ORB::create();
Mat descriptors_img1, descriptors_img2;


//-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
detector->detect(img1, kp1,descriptors_img1);
detector->detect(img2, kp2,descriptors_img2);


Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor = ORB::create();
extractor->compute(img1, kp1, descriptors_img1 );
extractor->compute(img2, kp2, descriptors_img2 );
//-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher
descriptors_img1.convertTo(descriptors_img1, CV_32F);
descriptors_img2.convertTo(descriptors_img2, CV_32F);
FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
std::vector<DMatch> matches;
matcher.match(descriptors_img1,descriptors_img2,matches);
double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

//-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_img1.rows; i++ )
{
    double dist = matches[i].distance;
    if( dist < min_dist )
        min_dist = dist;
    if( dist > max_dist )
        max_dist = dist;
}

printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist );
printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist );

//-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 3*min_dist )
std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_img1.rows; i++ )
{
    if( matches[i].distance < 3*min_dist )
    {
        good_matches.push_back( matches[i]);
    }
}

Mat img_matches;
drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good_matches,img_matches,Scalar::all(-1),
        Scalar::all(-1),vector<char>(),DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );
//-- Show detected matches
imshow( "Good Matches", img_matches );
```

But when I run it, I get error saying:

> OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (type=0
>   ) in buildIndex_, file /home/opencv-3.2.0/modules/flann/src/miniflann.cpp, line 315
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>     what():  /home/opencv-3.2.0/modules/flann/src/miniflann.cpp:315: error: (-210) type=0 in function buildIndex_

I looked at similar questions ,but i didnt find my answer.After debugging I came to know that error is at

```
matcher.match(....);
```

Please help me in fixing this out.Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include the error message in your question.

Comment: Now I edited and included the error message

Comment: I have tested out your code with OpenCV3.2 and VC14 but it worked fine. Are you sure you still have this error with the code you provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this error.
You just modify the code

```
Ptr<ORB> detector = ORB::create()
```

instead of

```
Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector = ORB::create();
```

Then it worked for me.